# Fragment Not Associated With A Fragment Manager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-espresso, android-architecture-navigation, instrumented-test

I am writing some instrumented tests for an app with one activity and multiple fragments using the `Navigation Component`.

The code for my splash screen is as below:

```
class SplashFragment : Fragment(), KodeinAware {

    override val kodein by Admin.instance.kodein

    private var realm: Realm? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        (activity as? AppCompatActivity)?.supportActionBar?.hide()

        realm = Realm.getInstance(RealmUtil.realmConfig)

        val result = realm!!.where<User>().findFirst()
        val user = if (result != null) realm!!.copyFromRealm(result) else null

        Handler().postDelayed({
            if (user == null)
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_splashFragment_to_loginFragment) //navigate to login screen if no user exists
            else
                findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_splashFragment_to_businessListFragment) //navigate to business list if user already logged in
        }, 2000)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        realm?.close()
    }
}
```

I am attempting to test a fragment that comes after the splash screen but I keep getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment SplashFragment{a1ca381 (5f5b98ae-c130-4e9b-9b77-0495561ef4f5)} not associated with a fragment manager.
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireFragmentManager(Fragment.java:891)
at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.findNavController(NavHostFragment.java:106)
at androidx.navigation.fragment.FragmentKt.findNavController(Fragment.kt:29)
at com.chargebot.collect.admin.fragment.onboarding.SplashFragment$onViewCreated$1.run(SplashFragment.kt:44)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.loopAndInterrogate(Interrogator.java:148)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:519)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:478)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.injectKeyEvent(UiControllerImpl.java:201)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.injectString(UiControllerImpl.java:357)
at androidx.test.espresso.action.TypeTextAction.perform(TypeTextAction.java:108)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:360)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:251)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.access$100(ViewInteraction.java:64)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:157)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:154)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

My test class is as follows:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@MediumTest
class SignInTest {

    @get: Rule
    val login = ActivityScenarioRule(Home::class.java)

    @Test
    fun loginWithoutEmail_ShouldDisplayError() {
        val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<LoginFragment>()

        onView(withId(R.id.password)).perform(typeText("samplePassword"), closeSoftKeyboard())
        onView(withId(R.id.login)).perform(click())

        onView(withId(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text)).check(matches(withText(R.string.enter_email)))
    }

    @Test
    fun loginWithoutPassword_ShouldDisplayError() {
        val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<LoginFragment>()

        onView(withId(R.id.email)).perform(typeText("sample@password.com"), closeSoftKeyboard())
        onView(withId(R.id.login)).perform(click())

        onView(withId(com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text)).check(matches(withText(R.string.enter_password)))
    }
}
```

None of my test functions will execute because of the aforementioned error. What's the cause of the exception since tests I run on the Splash screen run successfully?

My `nav_graph` is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/splashFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/splashFragment"
        android:name="com.chargebot.collect.admin.fragment.onboarding.SplashFragment"
        android:label="SplashFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/splash">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_splashFragment_to_loginFragment"
            app:destination="@id/loginFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/splashFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_splashFragment_to_businessListFragment"
            app:destination="@id/businessListFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/splashFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/registrationFragment"
        android:name="com.chargebot.collect.admin.fragment.onboarding.RegistrationFragment"
        android:label="RegistrationFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/registration">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_registrationFragment_to_businessListFragment"
            app:destination="@id/businessListFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/registrationFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_registrationFragment_to_loginFragment"
            app:destination="@id/loginFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/registrationFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:name="com.chargebot.collect.admin.fragment.onboarding.LoginFragment"
        android:label="LoginFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/login">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_businessListFragment"
            app:destination="@id/businessListFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/loginFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_registrationFragment"
            app:destination="@id/registrationFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/loginFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/businessListFragment"
        android:name="com.chargebot.collect.admin.fragment.business.BusinessListFragment"
        android:label="BusinessListFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/businesses_list">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_businessListFragment_to_newBusinessFragment"
            app:destination="@id/newBusinessFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_businessListFragment_to_branchesFragment"
            app:destination="@id/branchesFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/newBusinessFragment"
        android:name="com.chargebot.collect.admin.fragment.business.NewBusinessFragment"
        android:label="NewBusinessFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/add_business_layout">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_newBusinessFragment_to_businessListFragment"
            app:destination="@id/businessListFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/branchesFragment"
        android:name="com.chargebot.collect.admin.fragment.branch.BranchesFragment"
        android:label="BranchesFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/branches_layout">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_branchesFragment_to_transactionsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/transactionsFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_branchesFragment_to_newBranchFragment"
            app:destination="@id/newBranchFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_branchesFragment_to_collectorsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/collectorsFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/transactionsFragment"
        android:name="com.chargebot.collect.admin.fragment.transactions.TransactionsFragment"
        android:label="TransactionsFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/transactions" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/newBranchFragment"
        android:name="com.chargebot.collect.admin.fragment.branch.NewBranchFragment"
        android:label="NewBranchFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/add_branch_layout" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/collectorsFragment"
        android:name="com.chargebot.collect.admin.fragment.collector.CollectorsFragment"
        android:label="CollectorsFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/client_list_layout">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_collectorsFragment_to_newCollectorFragment"
            app:destination="@id/newCollectorFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_collectorsFragment_to_transactionsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/transactionsFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_collectorsFragment_to_collectorTransactions"
            app:destination="@id/collectorTransactions" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/newCollectorFragment"
        android:name="com.chargebot.collect.admin.fragment.collector.NewCollectorFragment"
        android:label="NewCollectorFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/new_client_layout" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/collectorTransactions"
        android:name="com.chargebot.collect.admin.fragment.transactions.CollectorTransactionsFragment"
        android:label="CollectorTransactions"
        tools:layout="@layout/transaction_layout">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_collectorTransactions_to_collectorsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/collectorsFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/collectorsFragment" />
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

Comment: can you post nav_graph xml ?

Comment: @Moinkhan please check updated question with `nav_graph`

Comment: Have you migrated the project from appcompat to androidx ? if that's the case change the fragment manager of appcompat to android x.

Comment: **can you rerun your test case again after commenting**    
         `Handler().postDelayed({
                if (user == null)
                    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_splashFragment_to_loginFragment) //navigate to login screen if no user exists
                else
                    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_splashFragment_to_businessListFragment) //navigate to business list if user already logged in
            }, 2000)`

Comment: @rajkavadia Yes, I'm using `AndroidX`. However, using the `Navigation Component`  means I needn't use the `FragmentManager`.

Comment: @TheVOYOU running it without the `Handler` works just fine but my use case requires there to be a delay before the next fragment is loaded.

Comment: @AlexKombo Were you able to solve this one, I have a similar case

Comment: @MayankSaini Yes. You can either use `Thread.sleep()` or an `IdlingResource`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I found out that in my case the issue was related to threading. I solved it with:

```
 lifecycleScope.launchWhenResumed {
      findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_splashFragment_to_loginFragment)
 }
```

Would be good to know if this help you?!

Comment: Yes, this helped me and looks like a cleaner approach than postDelayed.

Comment: if you are still using Java for Android dev in 2023 (yes legacy apps..) : `getLifecycle().getCurrentState().isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED);`

Answer (score 5):

Comment below code of yours

```
Handler().postDelayed({ 
   if (user == null) 
      findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_splashFragment_to_loginFragment) 
      //navigate to login screen if no user exists 
   else
      findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_splashFragment_to_businessListFragment) 
      //navigate to business list if user already logged in 
}, 2000)
```

If it works fine then

use `Thread.sleep(5000)` or `IdlingResource` to make a delay in your instrumentation test cases.

**Root Cause:**
Actually, during your test case runtime, you are trying to operate upon the fragment which is waiting on Handler for 2000 millies to execute.

Comment: I think your assumption is wrong. My NavController fails with same error: "Fragment Not Associated With A Fragment Manager" when I try to wait for 2 sec in corotuineScope and then findNavContoller.navigate somewhere

Comment: I mean, I wait, then check if I am still on that fragment, and only then navigate

Answer (score 1):

I just found this problem in my tests

[image: no associated with fragment manager]

By following [navigation test documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-testing) I was able to solve my problem creating a scenario for fragment with navController

```
val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer {
    TitleScreen().also { fragment ->

        // In addition to returning a new instance of our Fragment,
        // get a callback whenever the fragment’s view is created
        // or destroyed so that we can set the NavController
        fragment.viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.observeForever { viewLifecycleOwner ->
            if (viewLifecycleOwner != null) {
                // The fragment’s view has just been created
                navController.setGraph(R.navigation.trivia)
                Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java version using lifecycle:

```
getLifecycle().addObserver((LifecycleEventObserver) (lifecycleOwner, event) -> {
    if (event.getTargetState() == Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
        NavHostFragment.findNavController(MyFragment.this).navigateUp();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using code like this hope this will solve the issue

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
   //your code

}, 2000)
```